# How to Base64 encode an IntArray in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, base64

How to base64 encode a buff of `intArrayOf` using Kotlin.

```
val vec = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val data =?!
val base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the int array to an encoding/format that is sharable, like JSON, yaml, etc. The idea of converting a native array (of _any_ type) to base64 isn't logical

Comment: In other words how can we get the bin layout of it? idem byte[]

Comment: You can't get the bin layout directly; you'll have to convert it.  But there are different ways you could do that — *what do you need?*  (If all values are 0–255 (or -128–127), you could convert each int to a single byte.  Otherwise, you'll have to convert into multiple bytes: 4-byte ints, big- or little-endian; or text; or you could serialise the array object; or…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'ByteArray" representation of an `IntArray` can be calculated like this:

```
 fun IntArray.toByteArray(): ByteArray {

    val result = ByteArray(this.size * 4)

        for ((idx, value) in this.withIndex()) {
            result[idx + 3] = (value and 0xFF).toByte()
            result[idx + 2] = ((value ushr 8) and 0xFF).toByte()
            result[idx + 1] = ((value ushr 16) and 0xFF).toByte()
            result[idx] = ((value ushr 24) and 0xFF).toByte()
        }

        return result
    }
```

This result can then be Base64 encoded like mentioned in the question:

```
val vec = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val data = vec.toByteArray()
val base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Good solution, but I found that it is easy to use IntBuffer put my values and retrieve the array.